Is there any way to suppress the dim light shed by a manifested mind?
The Order of Scribes wizard subclass has the 6th level feature, Manifest Mind.

Tiny spectral object [...] The spectral mind is intangible and doesn’t occupy its space, and it sheds dim light in a 10-foot radius.

Is there any way to suppress that light?
Is there any way to suppress the light and still see?

Fog Cloud
Fog cloud will block any light as its area is heavily obscured. Unfortunately, it will also prevent the mind from seeing anything, so this is less useful for stealthy remote casting spells than you'd hope.
The alternative, darkness, I think is less likely to work. The mind does not say that it is magical, and the first time you conjure it after a long rest does not consume any spell slots, so technically according to the SAC criteria, that one is not magical. But it can be dispelled by dispel magic, and later conjurations consume spell slots, both pretty strong arguments that it is, so check with your DM. If its magical, darkness cannot suppress it, as darkness only suppresses nonmagical light and dispels spells creating light, and this is then is neither. However, even if the DM rules darkness works, this will still not allow you to use the manifest mind to cast through it if you need to see the target, because Manifested Mind only has darkvision, darkness trumps darkvision, and you are using its senses. So no Devil Sight tricks here.
I don't think there is a way to suppress this light and still see, outside of homebrewing something with the DM, or having the DM be very generous with the interpretation of an off-label wish spell. The Manifested Mind is a tiny spectral object, not even a creature, so there is no way to give it devil sight or blindsight, even if you could find a spell or magic item that would provide that to a creature.
Maybe, if the DM considers it to be nonmagical, you could use True Polymorph object to creature - a flying snake or a pseudodragon would have blindsight, be tiny, and be below CR 9, so they could see in darkness of fog. Since only the stat block of the creature changes, and your connection with the Manifest Mind is not part of a stat block, this could give you a pseudodragon manifest mind, that might even stick around permanently. Again, this is a level 9 spell and still will need a bunch of good will from your DM.

I'm going to cheat and update the question, which will change the relevance of this answer. I did upvote for accurately answering the question. :)

@Wyrmwood No problem. I added a short para on the new question -- unfortunately, I think there is nothing that will work without your DM playing ball.

Excellent. DM fiat is a perfectly acceptable answer when there is no rules-solution.
